# Quickfix Message header, body, trailer

Tags: quickfix

I have a quickfix message and I dont know which tags are trailer.

```
{8=FIX.4.2 9=61 35=8 34=100 49=FixServer 52=20150916-10:22:23.313 56=CLIENT1 10=192 }
```

Based on [header](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/javadoc/1.5.3/quickfix/fix41/Message.Header.html) I understand header includes 8, 49, 56.

But on [trailer](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/javadoc/1.5.0/quickfix/Message.Trailer.html) I dont know which tag are trailer.

Anyone here can give me a brief answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FIXimate is the resource you need:
http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/

This is the standard trailer:
http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/en/FIX.4.4/body_49485053.html

It's the same in all FIX versions.  Usually only tag 10 is used.  I've never seen anyone use 93 or 89.